# Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter inverse search

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to get hold of all NACLs that **do not** have the word "public" in the value  of the tag called Name.

I can see on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html that it is possible to carry out an inverse search.

However, everything I'm trying is failing.

For example, 
I declare the object and the tag:

```
        $inverseNameFilter = new-object Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter
        $inverseNameFilter.name = 'tag:Name'
```

And then these are the results I receive, for various methods I've tried:

```
        $inverseNameFilter.Value = '!public'
        (Get-EC2NetworkAcl -region $region -filter $inverseNameFilter).count
```

result: 0

```
        $inverseNameFilter.Value = '!*public*'
        (Get-EC2NetworkAcl -region $region -filter $inverseNameFilter).count
```

result: 0

```
        $inverseNameFilter.Value = '*public*'
        (Get-EC2NetworkAcl -region $region -filter $inverseNameFilter).count
```

result: 3
(So there are clearly three NACLs with Name tags containing public)

```
        (Get-EC2NetworkAcl -region $region).count
```

result: 18
(so there are clearly 18 NACLs in this region)

How do I carry out an inverse search to find the 15 NACLs that do not contain the word "public"?

Comment: Looking at [the API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TFilter.html), it doesn't seem like the filter supports negation :(

Comment: Ah thanks for that. Am I misreading the documentation that says "You can search for resources that do not match a specified value. For example, to list all instances that are not terminated, search by the Instance State field, and prefix the Terminated value with an exclamation mark (!)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the filter doesn't actually support negation (see comment by Mathias R. Jessen)

However, I've found a way to exclude the results using this PowerShell filtering rather than AWS filtering. It means the processing occurs at the client rather than at AWS, but gives me sufficient results:

```
(Get-EC2NetworkAcl -region $region | Where-Object -FilterScript { ([string]$_.tags.Value) -notmatch "public"}).count
```

15